# Python Selenium: Element currently not visible

Tags: python, selenium

I have this [page](https://gleam.io/Myap1/the-forest-giveaway). I have to click on Facebook icon. Upon doing it I m getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Code is given below:

```
if 'log' in html.lower():
        print("not logged in")
        sleep(3)
        #Click on Fb button
        fb_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@tooltip="Facebook"]')
        fb_element.vis
        fb_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an another element with `tooltip="Facebook"` on the page and this element is actually invisible. Well, there are actually 10 of them:

```
> $x('//a[@tooltip="Facebook"]').length
10
```

You can find find all elements matching your locator and filter the visible one via `next()` and `is_displayed()`:

```
facebook_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@tooltip="Facebook"]')
visible_link = next(link for link in facebook_links if link.is_displayed())
visible_link.click()
```

Comment: Ah - So my assumption to have only one such element was wrong. Your code worked like charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Volatil3 yeah, I've also briefly tried to narrow down the locator to make it uniquely identify the desired link, but I've got 5 instead of 10 at best with my attempts. Filter visible only does not sound like a bad idea in this case :)